# python pandas dataframe: create a column in 2nd dataframe with aggregate values acc to matching item from 1st dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df1:
id | country | state | amt1 | amt2 | var1 | var2
1 | US | TX | 20 | 40 | a | X
2 | US | CA | 30 | 900 | b  | Y
3 | US | CA | 40 | 230 | c | X
4 | US | TX | 80 | 670 | d | X
5 | US | NY | 20 | 120 | a | Y
6 | US | TX | 10 | 80 | c | X
```

This is an example dataframe - the original dataframe I have has multiple other columns, with different types of variables

I would like to create another dataframe which will contain aggregrates (sum/count/any other function) of any column from the 1st dataframe, per matching country, state

For this, I have already created the 2nd dataframe with groupings of the country, state:

```
df2:
country | state | num
US | TX | 3
US | CA | 2
US | NY | 1
```

Now, I want to be able to add any column to df2, which will contain the sum of "amt1" from "df1" for the matching country & state

I am able to do this using iterrows:

```
for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    amt = df1[(df1.state == df2.state ) & (df1.country == df2.country )].amt1.sum()
    df2.set_value(i, 'Amt ', amt)
```

However that is taking a lot of time, for a large dataset

Wanted to know if there is any alternative way of doing this efficiently, instead of using iterrows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on my understanding, you just need `groupby` your df1, get the sum of amt1, then `merge` with df2

```
df2.merge(df1.groupby(['country','state'],as_index=False).amt1.sum())
Out[792]: 
  country state  num  amt1
0      US    TX    3   110
1      US    CA    2    70
2      US    NY    1    20
```

Comment: That Worked... Thanks!

Comment: @Ritu Yw~ : -) happy coding